# running command line using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to run the following  command line

```
'C:\Program Files\CloudCompare>CloudCompare -o C:\CloudComparetest\test.bin -SS SPATIAL 0.1'
```

It works well ( see image) when I follow this way:

window-->cmd and type it directly there.

But I need to run this command inside matlab job.
Online search gives me this pattern to run simple commands:

It works:

```
     command = 'C:\Program Files\CloudCompare\CloudCompare.exe';
     [status,cmdout] = system(command)
status=0;
```

But trying this gives me errors: (I know it is not  standard dos command...may be any other solution.

```
    %  command = 'C:\Program Files\CloudCompare>CloudCompare -o C:\CloudComparetest\test.bin -SS SPATIAL 0.1';
    %  status = dos(command)
status=1;
```

I also tried

```
%  command = 'C:\Program Files\CloudCompare\CloudCompare -o C:\CloudComparetest\test.bin -SS SPATIAL 0.1';
%  status = dos(command)
```

status=1;

[image]

Error: while running cloud.bat

Either the command is not correct or can not be found.

```
 dos('"C:\MyPHDCODE\COLOR_SCANS\cloud.bat"')
C:\MyPHDCODE\Chapter5\COLORIMAGES>C:\Program Files\CloudCompare\CloudCompare -o C:\CloudComparetest\test.bin -SS SPATIAL 0.1 pause  
Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder 
konnte nicht gefunden werden. 

ans =

     1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you have a space in your path name, and a >. Replace > with \ and enclose the command in "", this will let cmd run the command correctly (if there are no other errors)

Put this in a text file called cloud.bat:
`"C:\Program Files\CloudCompare\CloudCompare" -o C:\CloudComparetest\test.bin -SS SPATIAL 0.1
pause`

(SPATIAL 0.1 should be on the same line as the rest, pause on a new line)

Then call cloud.bat from the dos command. You should place cloud.bat in your current MatLab directory.

EDIT: what I meant here is that you should call cloud.bat from MatLab, I can see that it can be misunderstood.

When this is run you can see any error messages from CloudCompare.

Comment: i tried ''C:\Program Files\CloudCompare\CloudCompare -o C:\CloudComparetest\test.bin''' but no sucess'''. It didn't work.

Comment: Is it the correct path? To test, you could put the command in a bat-file, followed by pause, call the bat from matlab, then you could see the error message from cmd

Comment: i don't understand bat-file concept.  I think problem is space. I donot know how to finish it.

Comment: When I look at your examples that work, you use different commands (dos and system), but they should both do the same. The second example is clearly wrong, > is a redirect character, not te be used in a path. Your command window example does not include the -SS switch?

Comment: You still should use "" around the path+command, as shown in my edited cloud.bat example. The error you get means that the command interpreter thinks c:\program is a command. It breaks because of the space in program files. "" tells the command interpreter to use the complete string as the command